# Pandas create rows based on values of several previous columns for a given number of preceding rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, like so:

```
A B  C
1 11 33
2 15 46 
3 12 91
1  8 75
3 35 63
2 22 52
```

I'm creating columns N, M and O based on those values for the previous *x* rows:

- N is the number amongst those rows where B > this row's B and C < this row's C
- M is the number amongst those rows where the above conditions aren't true **and** A == 1
- O is the number where either condition for N isn't met and A!=1

The first *x* rows are then dropped.

(as a consequence, N+M+0 always == *x*)

Expected output when *x*==2:

```
A B  C  N M O
3 12 91 1 0 1  
1  8 75 0 1 1
3 35 63 2 0 0
2 22 52 2 0 0
```

My solution, since I could not come up with a pure pandas approach, is to simply iterate over rows and use 3 different counters:

```
    x=17 # "17" is not actually hardcoded, it's read from file
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        n=0
        m=0
        o=0
        for j in range(1, x+1):
            if row.B > df.iloc[i-j].B and row.B < df.iloc[i-j].C:
                n+=1
            elif df.iloc[i-j].A == 1:
                m+=1
            else: 
                o+=1
        df.at[i,"N"] = n
        df.at[i,"M"] = m
        df.at[i,"O"] = o         
     df=df.iloc[x:]
```

It works, but is, obviously, quite slow (the df is large). 
Is this possible to do without iterating over the rows? If so, how?

Comment: Can you share expected output dataframe?

Comment: @min2bro Sure. Edited the question to have a clearer example.

Comment: Should 'm' be 1in the first row `3 12 91 1 0 1` ? As my understanding the first row don't match with the 'N' condition and A==1.

Answer (score 0):

We can get it using `merge` and `lambda` as below

```
df1 = df.merge(df.apply(lambda row: createMNO(row), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

please find the complete example below. Need to correct the comparison logic, if my understanding about your logic is incorrect.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.loc[len(df)] = [1,11,33]
df.loc[len(df)] = [2,15,46]
df.loc[len(df)] = [3,12,91]
df.loc[len(df)] = [1,8,75]
df.loc[len(df)] = [3,35,63]
df.loc[len(df)] = [2,22,52]

x = 2 

def createMNO(row):
    subDF = df.loc[row.name - x :row.name - 1]
    n = len(subDF.loc[(subDF.B > row.B) & (subDF.C < row.C)])
    m = len(subDF.loc[~((subDF.B > row.B) & (subDF.C < row.C)) & (subDF.A == 1)])
    o = x - m - n
    return pd.Series({
        'N' : n,
        'M' : m,
        'O' : o
    })

df1 = df.merge(df.apply(lambda row: createMNO(row), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(df1.iloc[x:])
```

Comment: It works (comparison logic doesn't match, but that's an easy fix), but it's not really any faster.